# Within Jira automatically closing tickets with a link "Relates To"

Tags: jira, jython, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am looking for a way to have Jira automatically close our help desk tickets when our development tickets are closed.  With Jira we have two projects DEV and HD (help desk).  When we create a HD ticket we also create a corresponding DEV ticket that our developer commits code to.  When we deploy we close the development ticket, but often the associated HD ticket is forgotten about (each HD ticket is linked to the corresponding DEV ticket by the issue link 'Relates To').

Is there something with workflow, a plugin, the REST API, or Jython that would give us the capability to automatically close the associated help desk ticket that is linked to the dev ticket?  Is this something that would have to be custom done or is there already something out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Script Runner add-on has a script to close issues in a certain state after some time. I would take that script and customize it to also test for linked issues where the link type is "Relates To" and the linked issues are closed. You can use Jython for that or groovy

~Matt